# Only seeing Index of/ at domain even though index.js is present in the pubic_html directory

Tags: node.js

I've been driving myself a little mad trying to deploy this node.js and express app

I'm hosting on bluehost, so therefor, deploying via cpanel -

Currently:

Git repo cloned and deployed head commit success

Node app registered in app manager and Npm dependencies have been successfully ensured.

I after cd'ing into my repository directory in cpanel terminal I ran

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs10/bin/node app.js
```

and it was confirmed that

```
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

Then after logging into whm root I ran

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

And am returned with my index.ejs file , which seems like a good sign.

However, when I go to my domain -- deltadesigns.co

All you can see is :

Index of /
Name    Last modified   Size    Description
DeltaDesigns22/ 2021-02-27 06:23    -
cgi-bin/    2021-02-19 03:00    -

DeltaDesigns22 is the repo with all of required files and folders, public, views, app.js cpanel.yml etc.

I can't figure out why it's not working, feel like I'm so close but am just missing something! All help is appreciated!

Comment: So you have DNS records for your domain pointing to your server, right? You also have some reverse proxy like nginx or apache listening on port 80 and/or 443 to proxy the requests to your app, right?

Comment: Yes the domain is the primary domain for this cpanel account and its selection has been checked. And to the second part, I think so? I'm quite sure this happened when installing apache packages through the root in whm. What would be good ways to double check the listening port?

Comment: Well i don't use apache so won't help you with that. But it is obvious that it is not configured correctly.